# Need help in Like%

Tags: sas

I have small query on like condition:

```
proc sql;
  create table test as 
  select *
  from Outlier_32
  where 
    DX1 like between 'B0%' and 'C10' or 
    DX2 like between 'B0%' and 'C10' or
    DX3 like between 'B0%' and 'C10' or
    DX4 like between 'B0%' and 'C10'
  ;
quit;
```

Basically I have a diagnosis range with me and want to filet (filter?) the data in all 4 dx columns.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative select criteria can use Perl regular expression pattern matching against a concatenation of the diagnosis code variables.  The concatenation role is the same as `or` testing individual variables.

```
where prxmatch ('/(B|C)0/', cats(dx1,dx2,dx3,dx4))
```

In a broader and long range epidemiological study sense you may consider having a ontology table that maps diagnosis codes to disease cluster or study category.

```
dx    category
---   --------
B00   Foo
… 
B99   Foo
C00   Foo
…
C09   Foo
```

`dx` would be foreign keyed to a master list of all diagnostic codes.

Then the SQL query selection criteria would involve the existence of a correlated sub-query match.

```
where
  exists (select * from ontology where category = 'Foo' and dx1 = dx) or
  exists (select * from ontology where category = 'Foo' and dx2 = dx) or
  exists (select * from ontology where category = 'Foo' and dx3 = dx) or
  exists (select * from ontology where category = 'Foo' and dx4 = dx)
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant use multiple sql conditional operators `like & beteewn` in one conditional statments `DX1 like between 'B0%' and 'C10'` .

Means `=,<>,like,between` are sql conditional operators, you have to use one at a time ' `Example:  WHERE(DX1 LIKE 'B0%' OR DX1 BETWEEN 'B0' AND 'C10')`.

[Like](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp) is a wild card operator used to filter column data by pattern.

> WHERE CustomerName LIKE 'a%'  Finds any values that start with "a"
>   
>  WHERE CustomerName LIKE '%a'    Finds any values that end with "a"
>   
>  WHERE CustomerName LIKE '%or%'  Finds any values that have "or"
>   in any position 
>  WHERE CustomerName LIKE '*r%'   Finds any values
>   that have "r" in the second position 
>  WHERE CustomerName LIKE
>   'a*%_%'   Finds any values that start with "a" and are at least 3
>   characters in length 
>  WHERE ContactName LIKE 'a%o'   Finds any
>   values that start with "a" and ends with "o"

I'm not sure about the data type and values in your column DX1,DX2; but as per for question to `filter data by range`, you may use `between` operator.

```
WHERE DX1 BETWEEN 'B00' AND 'C10' 
  AND DX2 BETWEEN 'B00' AND 'C10'
  AND DX3 BETWEEN 'B00' AND 'C10' 
  AND DX4 BETWEEN 'B00' AND 'C10';
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no operation `like between`.  You can use truncated comparisons. The colon modifier after the operator tells SAS to compare only up to the length of the shorter argument. Note there is no need to use SQL for something a simple data step can do.

```
data test ;
  set Outlier_32 ;
  where (DX1 >=: 'B0' and DX1 <= 'C10')
     or (DX2 >=: 'B0' and DX2 <= 'C10')
     or (DX3 >=: 'B0' and DX3 <= 'C10')
     or (DX4 >=: 'B0' and DX3 <= 'C10')
  ;
quit;
```